# cURL Upload file to a distant server behind a proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file by FTP to a distant server but I have to use a proxy for doing it.
I'm using cURL in command line. Here the command I'm trying to execute:

```
curl -x http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxyIp:proxyPort -T test.csv ftp://ftpUser:ftpPassword@ftpUrl:ftpPort
```

Here the message I got:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I try different configuration, but I can't get to the server. When I'm trying to connect to the FTP server from another webserver without proxy, it works, so I guess this is either the proxy which is not configure correctly or my curl command which is missing something.

If you have any ideas on how I can be able to upload a file.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the problem.
I had to use the socks5 protocol instead of http.
The corrected function is:

```
curl -x socks5://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxyIp:proxyPort -T test.csv ftp://ftpUser:ftpPassword@ftpUrl:ftpPort
```